# Why in R are grep & !grep not logically consistent when grepl and !grepl ARE logically consistent?

Tags: r, grepl

R functions `grep` and `!grep` (NOT grep) are not logically consistent; unlike `grepl` and `!grepl` (NOT grepl) which ARE logically consistent.

`grepl` returns a logical vector equal in length to the number of items being searched. For example, if the target is found in items 2 and 3 of a 5-item vector the following is returned:

```
FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If `grepl` is replaced by `!grepl`, then the "opposite" logical result is returned:

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

`grep`, on other hand returns a vector of the 2 positions of the found items: `2 3`

What does `!grep` return in the same scenario? Logically it should return `1 4 5`, instead it returns `FALSE FALSE`. How can that be a logically consistent returned value? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Since `grep` returns a 0+ vector of `integer`s, the `!` (invert logic) operator is not defined on them. Can you tell me with certainty what `invert_logic 5:7` means? (If you know the length of the vector, then you can infer `1:4,8:n`, but that's presumptuous.) Since `grepl` returns a 0+ vector of `logical`s, it is meaningful to say `invert_logic c(T,T,F,T)`, and since you are indexing a vector with a same-length vector of logicals (inverted or otherwise), you're good. (BTW: `letters[ -grep("[f-h]", letters ]` is effectively inverting.)

Comment: Try `grep(..., invert = TRUE)`.  I think that's what you want.

Comment: 1) `grep` returns the indices that matches the pattern, while `grepl` returns a logical vector; 2) the `!` operator coerces its argument to `logical`. Try `!c(0,2,4)` for instance and you will see that it's equivalent to `!as.logical(c(0,2,4))`; 3) check the `invert` argument of `grep`.

Comment: @r2evans "the `!` (invert logic) operator is not defined on integer" is not true. You can use `!` on `integer` and `numeric` vectors.

Comment: Okay, I'll concede that, and I'll counter with `! 5:7` yielding `F,F,F` is counter-intuitive if you aren't thinking that `0` and `FALSE` are equivalent. Thanks for the correction (you're absolutely right), and that further highlights why it won't work (and, admittedly, perhaps some inconsistency in how R and other languages convert types to/from booleans).

Comment: @r2evans Don't get  why the `!5:7` example is counter-intuitive and which inconsistencies you are talking about. 0 is `FALSE` and any other number is `TRUE` when coerced to `logical`, that's it.

Comment: In the context of the OP, I inferred that the expectation of `! grep(...)` is to select the opposite indices, not turn all numbers into `FALSE`. (I frequently (ab)use conditionals like `if (length(x)) { ... }`, implying that a non-zero number is `TRUE` and 0 is `FALSE`.) You're right, @nicola, and those learning the use of `grep{,l}` just need to learn the appropriate use-cases.

Comment: @r2evans I got it. What the OP should realize is that `!grep` is *not* a function (as they seem to imply), but are two functions and the `!` operator is applied to the result yielded by `grep` and doesn't change the behavior of `grep`.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `invert` argument to `grep()`.

From `help(grep)`, under *Arguments*:

> **invert** - logical. If `TRUE` return indices or values for elements that do *not* match.

Sounds like exactly what you want.  Let's see an example.

```
x <- c("ab", "cd", "bc", "def", "abc")

grep("b", x)
# [1] 1 3 5
grep("b", x, invert=TRUE)
# [1] 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

grep(value = FALSE) - returns a vector of the indices of the elements of x that yielded a match.

grepl returns a logical vector (match or not for each element of x).

[grep vs grepl in R](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-grep-and-grepl-in-R)